# How to schedule weekly LocalNotification with different alert message in objective c iphone

Tags: iphone

Here, I have an array:

```
weeklySnippets = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"Message 1"
                          , @"Message 2"
                          , @"Message 3"
                          , @"Message 4"
                          , @"Message 5"];
```

How should I change notification alert message as per array index for every week:
e.g. when week=1 it should show first message at index=0 i.e "Message 1" and so on..

```
UILocalNotification *notifWeek = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notifWeek.fireDate = [NSDate date];
notifWeek.alertBody = notifText;
notifWeek.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options, my choice would be #2:

1. Schedule a weekly recurring notification, then access `scheduledLocalNotifications` in your App Delegate and change the message of each notification.
2. Create a different notification for each week, using something like:

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i > [weeklySnippets count]; i++) {

       UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

       // Set the fire date by one week increments (1 week = 604800 seconds)
       // First object in array fires one week from now (i + 1)
       notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:604800 * (i+1)];

       NSString *notificationText = [weeklySnippets objectAtIndex:i];

       notification.alertBody = notificationText;
   }
   ```